# Working in CMYK mode but exported colors is wrong. which one will be printed?

Tags: cmyk

i have a CMYK psd and i know it has different colors with RGB ... but i have a odd issue, in photoshop, even in my CMYK psd, everything is good. but when i export it as a CMYK JPG, the result in any image viewer (except photoshop itself) is different from what i see in photoshop. its darker and colors are not what i see in photoshop (they are both CMYK)

i search about it and i find out that image viewers, dosent support CMYK jpg. and its ok... my question is, when i print this design, which one will be on the paper? the one that i see in CMYK PSD Photoshop? or the one that i see in image viewer?

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE!

Comment: Normally you wouldn't ever send CMYK JPGs for print as far as I know. You would send a PDF exported with the proper settings, bleed and crop marks. But in general you should trust the preview you get in Photoshop. As you say yourself, other image viewers might not display CMYK images correctly.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. This is normal. Nothing is wrong. Most image viewers don't support CMYK colour. That's why it doesn't look right.  Also note that most office/home inkjet printers can't print CMYK files either - they are set up to print RGB files.  CMYK images are mostly used for print technologies which require separations, such as offset litho or screen printing.

Answer (score 1):

Printed where?

First, some non asked comments:

I have bad news. CMYK mode is only necessary for commercial print like sheetfed offset, where you separate the colors on plates to print 1000 posters. Some other printers can use directly the CMYK information, but in most cases, inkjet printers, office-level printers will use RGB.

A more suitable workflow is using RGB color mode with a CMYK preview, and this preview can change depending on the CMYK profile you need for the output.

If the print system you will use can use the CMYK file directly it's ok. If not it will change to some RGB mode and then will change it back to the specific CMYK mode the specific printer needs. This will render duller colors than a direct RGB file can provide.

---

For your specific question, if the bureau you are using is professional enough, they will use software that takes into account the CMYK mode. They will not use just a file viewer.

The best answer would be to ask them.

Comment: I would add one minor point to this: if CMYK jpeg is not widely supported in software (it isn't), then it would be safer to *not submit a CMYK jpg*. After it is printed, they have to pay for it, so why not submit something they are sure will print correctly and avoid the need to hope?